# Outside HTML Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to get my webpage to use the kind of color box that is demoed on this website here.
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/. (Outside HTML ajax Example).

In their code for this, they have:

```
$(".ajax").colorbox();
```

targeting:

```
<p>
    <a class='ajax' href="../content/ajax.html" title="Homer Defined">
        Outside HTML (Ajax)
    </a>
</p>
```

My question is, I want the colorbox to display another page I have, when I click this Icon span on my page.

```
<span id="pause">
    <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
</span>
```

I've used `on()` to make it so when it's clicked it runs a function.

```
$("#pause").on("click", function() {
    game.pause();
});
```

Where as `game.pause();` will create this effect, but I'm not sure how to make it happen, because I am not using a link like the examples.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Oh, sorry I would have. I figured it out and then forgot to check back here for answers :).